# Citing a book where no formatting of text is possible

Tags: punctuation, citation

In forums such as this, where it's not possible to format the title of a question, is there an appropriate way to refer to a title of a book? For example, in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89431/exercise-7-7-1-in-grimmett-stirzakers-probability-and-random-processes) I enclose the title of a textbook in quotes. Is that okay?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the tag options here, so re-tagging will be appreciated.

Comment: Insider's tip: avoid referring to any Stack Exchange site as a 'forum', [some people](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stackoverflow-a-forum) are known to get twitchy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. For example, a typeset Chicago Manual citation:

> Surname, Given. *Title.* City: Publisher, 2011.

can be represented in plain text as:

```
Surname, Given. "Title." City: Publisher, 2011.
```

AP style allows underline (for historical reasons, because it is available on a manual typewriter). As StackExchange markdown does not support underline, I do not give an example.

Comment: Thanks. Can't you just use HTML here on StackExchange to underline text?

Comment: Quinn, neither html encoding, nor the ** method work in the question title.  Only in the body.

Comment: @SkipHuffman, some confusion here. MetaEd refers to StackExchange markdown in his answer, which doesn't apply to titles (as you say), but Quinn has a point - you can use HTML in the body.

Comment: If there is markdown for underline which works in the body I would love to know about it. The HTML U element is ignored.

Comment: You are right @MetaEd underscore is not one of the basic formatting tools provided.